# How to solve no overload for method takes 1 arguments C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a class with arrays which goes like this..

```
public class CardList
{
    public string[] GetImages() {
        // Create a new instance of a string array
        string[] images = new string[108];
        images[1] = @"C:\Resources\ALLCARDS\YellowCards\0 Yellow.png";
        ...
        ...
        images[107] = @"C:\Resources\ALLCARDS\BlackCards\Draw4.png";

        return images;
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to call the array to another class and assign it to a picturebox. This what I did..

```
private void pictureBox16_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CardList List = new CardList();
    List.GetImages();

    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = List.GetImages(1);
}
```

But I have red lines below the "List.GetImages(1);" that says "no overload for method takes 1 arguments".

Comment: `public string[] GetImages()` is defined with no arguments; you have not provided a way to fetch 1 image only a List of all of them

Comment: Note that arrays in C# start at index 0 and not 1

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about language fundamentals on the subject of "methods". We expect a basic knowledge of the language since Stack Overflow is not a substitute for a book, class, tutorial or common sense.

Comment: Besides the question asked, as this methods seems to have nothing to do with the class instance, it should probably be `static`, so you can call it directly `CardList.GetImages()`. Another suggestion: use camel case for objects. I.e.: `CardList list = ...`.

Comment: @Zainul, I rolled back your two latest edits. This question is poor enough, changing it into another one is borderline abusive. If you have another question, please post it as another question (hopefully *after* researching the problem by yourself).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
string[] images = List.GetImages();
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = images[1];
```

Comment: Any idea how to set a random image instead of image[1];

Comment: @ZainulAriffin beyond the scope of this question I guess.

Comment: @ZainulAriffin, have you tried doing some research? You have to use the `Random` class. http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

On your `List.GetImages(1)` line, you are trying to call the `GetImages()` function, passing a `1` as an argument when your function takes none. Your code should look like:

```
    string[] images = List.GetImages();
    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = images[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get this error is that the `GetImages` method doesn't have any parameters. See the signature:

```
public string[] GetImages() // nothing between () => no parameters
```

That method has no parameters, and returns an array. You can access the first item in that array using `0` (in C# indexes are 0-based).

```
string[] images = GetImages();
string first = images[0];
```

It's always best to check the array has actually the index you want to get, you can do it by checking the `Length`:

```
string[] images = GetImages();

if (images != null && images.Length > 0)
{
    string first = images[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `getimages()` function takes no parameters and you are trying to pass in 1. So unless you define another `getimages()` function that takes an `int` parameter (method overloading), you are going to get the error `"no overload for method takes 1 arguments"`

Answer (score -1):

You can overload `GetImages` method simply by:

```
public string[] GetImages(int index) {
    // Create a new instance of a string array
    string[] images = new string[108];

    images[1] = @"C:\Resources\ALLCARDS\YellowCards\0 Yellow.png";
    ...
    ...
    images[107] = @"C:\Resources\ALLCARDS\BlackCards\Draw4.png";

    if(images.Length > index - 1)
        return images[index];

    return null;
}
```

Comment: So if `index` equals 1000, you will get a beautiful error. ;)